# JWT malformed: stored my jwt token in cookies

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, axios

so i am trying to run an api route on the frontend of my application but each time i do i get a jwt malformed response even though the token is been passed to the client side as cookies i don't seem to get what the problem is because it works in the backend when i test it out with thunder client

```
class Authentication {
    public static generateToken(id: number, userName: string): string {
        const secretKey: string = process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY || "richmond-ekezie-richard-031";
        const payload: Payload = { userId: id, userName: userName };
        const option = { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN };

        return jwt.sign(payload, secretKey, option)
    }

    public static validationToken(token: string): Payload | null {
        try {
            const secretKey: string = process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY || "richmond-ekezie-richard-031"
            return jwt.verify(token, secretKey) as Payload;
        } catch (error) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**THIS IS TO GENERATE THE AUTHENTICATION THE USER **

`export function verifyToken(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
let secretKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY || "richmond-ekezie-richard-031";

```
if (!req.headers['authorization']) return next(res.status(401).send("No token!"))
const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
const bearerToken = authHeader.split(' ')
const token = bearerToken[1]

jwt.verify(token, secretKey, (err: any, payload: any) => {
    if (err) {
        return next(res.send(err))
    }
    req.payload = payload.Id
    next()
})
```

}`

**THIS IS TO VERIFY THE TOKEN THAT IS BEIGN SENT **

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //  function decodeJWT(token) {
    //     if (token) {
    //         // Decode the JWT token (only the payload part)
    //         const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
    //         const base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
    //         return JSON.parse(atob(base64));
    //     } else {
    //         console.error('JWT token not found in the cookie');
    //         return null;
    //     }
    // }
    const form = document.querySelector('form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', async function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const plan = form.paymentPlan.value;
        const amount = form.amount.value;
        const token = document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('jwt='));

        if (!token) {
            console.error('JWT token not found in the cookie')
        }else{
            const tokenCookie = token.split('=')[1];
        }

        const newAmount = parseInt(amount)

        try {
            const response = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: '/api/deposit/payment',
                data: {plan, amount},
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, 
                }
            });
            alert(response.data.message);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            alert('Failed to make payment.');
        }
    });
</script>
```

**AND THIS IS THE JAVASCRIPT FOR THE HTML FORM**

I would like to know what is wrong with the code or how i can reslove it, i have already tested the token on jwt.io and its a valid token

Comment: You seem to extract the token value in the `tokenCookie` variable (without the `jwt=`), but you use the variable `token` when you send the request, is it intended?